# Schematic for TTGO VGA32 V1.2 by Lilygo

Tags: microcontroller, schematics, vga, ps2

After recieving a couple of these boards to tinker with I have been searching online for some schematic. I have only found the following useful images:

- Block Diagrams with several pinouts described such as the one that can be found on the [github page from the forked graphics library FabGL by LilyGo](https://github.com/LilyGO/FabGL):

[image: TTGO VGA32 V1.2 interface pinout]

- Mechanical and other drawings found from the [product page of Lilygo](http://www.lilygo.cn/claprod_view.aspx?TypeId=21&Id=1217):
  [image: TTGO VGA32 V1.2 mechanical layout]
- Block Diagrams from the Microcontroller TTGO Micro itself from a [product page of the micro](https://www.tindie.com/products/ttgo/lilygor-ttgo-micro-32-v20/): 
  [image]

Other usefull resources I have found are:

- [Generic esp32 schematic from Fabgl Lib](http://www.fabglib.org/gen_schema.html) which the board is compatible with.
- Multiple reverse-engineered schematics of other TTGO board such as this one from [hackaday](https://hackaday.io/project/166482-meshington/log/165537-first-pass-at-schematic) or [bytebang](https://www.bytebang.at/download/Blog/Porting+LuaRTOS+to+the+TTGO+LoRa32+Board/TTGO_Lora_32_Schematic.png)

But none of the actual TTGO VGA32 Board.

I know that to use the board with the information provided, its enough but wanted to get more detail on the board.

So before I go and invest some time into reverse engineering my own schematic, which I probably will do eventualy I'm asking if anyone has done this already or knows where to find the schematic of the TTGO VGA32 V1.2 Board?

I also asked the question to have a placeholder to be able to find/share the Schematic of this board easier in the future.

Cheers

Comment: You can find the schematic of the V1.4 board on the Lilygo github fork of the FabGL repository
https://github.com/LilyGO/FabGL/blob/master/Schematic/vga32_v1.4.pdf
cheers
Lawrence VE7IT

Comment: Thanks Lawrence, This will definitely help me out when I actually find the time to tinker with the board... can you believe it, a year later and I still haven't found time to tinker with the boards... :(, Too many ideas , too little time xD